# IPhone performSelector issue

Tags: iphone, selector

I have working code:
 [self performSelector:@selector(doSomething) ];

but when I change this line to:

[self performSelector:@selector(doSomething) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];

it reports error - unrecognized selector....

could you tell me what is the problem in?

thank you

Comment: post more code, please. If the ..@selector(doSomething:) does not work, something goes really wrong with your methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you changed your method to take an object parameter then you need to change the `@selector()` argument to include the ":", e.g., `@selector( doSomething: )`

This works:

```
- (void) foo
{
    NSLog(@"foo!");
}


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification 
{        
    [self performSelector: @selector(foo) withObject: nil afterDelay: 0.1];
}
```

So you can pass a selector that takes no param to `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` and I presume it ignores the `withObject:` param which I wasn't 100% sure of.

Comment: hmm. your comment to another proposed answer suggests that something else is going on.  Post the doSomething method code?

Comment: Maybe give us the actual error message, does it say _which_ selector is unrecognized?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is that your selector is `doSomething` and not `doSomething:`. Without the `:`, there's nowhere in the message to insert an object, even `nil`.

Comment: [self performSelector:@selector(doSomething:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
still the same error

Comment: See below, simple test code that shows that you don't seem to have to have a selector that takes an object when using `peformSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`... (I wasn't sure on this so had to write a quick test to confirm).

Answer (score 0):

Is self still around? You could be trying to send a message to an NSZombie.