# Unrecognized selector sent to instance, performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: and Delegates

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, unrecognized-selector

using xCode 5 with ARC, Objective-C

I have simple program, where I add additional class with protocol for new delegate (very simple).

**ArrayGenerator.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@protocol ArrayGeneratorDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)StartTask:(NSMutableArray*)array;
@end

@interface ArrayGenerator : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ArrayGeneratorDelegate> delegate;
-(void)ArrayGenerator;
@end
```

**ArrayGenerator.m**

```
#import "ArrayGenerator.h"
@implementation ArrayGenerator

-(void) ArrayGenerator{
//create selector for method in Protocol
SEL mySelector = @selector(StartTask:); 
if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(StartTask:) ] ){   
    //call to method    
    [self performSelector:mySelector withObject:array afterDelay:1];
}
@end
```

and

in **ViewController.h** I add

```
#import "ArrayGenerator.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ArrayGeneratorDelegate>
@end
```

in **ViewController.m** I add

```
 ...
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
ArrayGenerator *ag = [[ArrayGenerator alloc ]init];
ag.delegate = self;
[ag ArrayGenerator];
}
...
-(void)StartTask:(NSMutableArray*)array{
NSLog( @"StartTask" );
}
```

So I achieve, that after running app in 1 second in Log i could see "StartTask", but instead of this i simply got Exception like

`DelegatesWithDelay[2240:90b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ArrayGenerator StartTask:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b55200'`

[image]

Spend a lot of time to find something similar problem with described solution (here and other sites, but nothing from that not help's).

Also find an alternative solution:
instead of `[self performSelector:mySelector withObject:array afterDelay:1];` I call to `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self.delegate selector:mySelector userInfo:nil repeats:NO];` - and all it's work fine, but I want to know why first variant with `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` not work??? (**Question**)

[image]

Also try to:

- recreate project - almost different - not help -same problem with
  this method, but with NSTimer - al works;
- change [@property attributs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3861653/2012219) from (nonatomic, weak), to
  (nonatomic, release) (as was recommended in some solution to similars
  problem - not help
- try [to use another variants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6729374/2012219) of performSelector methods - not
  helps
- try to [change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3126431/2012219) `mySelector` to `@selector(StartTask:)` - not
  helps

and so on....nothing help, maybe i miss something?

Comment: try to replace : "[self performSelector:mySelector withObject:array afterDelay:1];" by "[self.delegate performSelector:mySelector withObject:array afterDelay:1];"

Comment: if i put [self.delegate], i can only use ` [self.delegate performSelector:mySelector ];` or ` [self.delegate performSelector:mySelector withObject:someObject];` but without Delay, and Yes, it's work

Comment: ios 9.1 support arm64 after this error reason [NSTaggedPointerString delegate]  unrecognised selector sent.. please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be this:

```
if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(StartTask:) ] ){     
     NSInteger delay = 1;
     dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delay * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          [self.delegate performSelector:mySelector withObject:array];
     });
}
```

Your self (`ArrayGenerator`) has no selector `StartTask`, but your delegate does.

Comment: yes, this solution works fine, i understand where is the problem was

Comment: Oh and for convention: change StartTask to startTask, and change your method ArrayGenerator into something else. You might get confused on whether you want the NSObject or the method.

Comment: ios 9.1 support arm64 after this error reason [NSTaggedPointerString delegate] unrecognised selector sent.. please help me

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found real reason for this exception (that described in question).

The method `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` is defined on NSObject - but id works for more than just NSObject (so i must to be more specific than just 'id').

What need to change -

```
@interface ArrayGenerator : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ArrayGeneratorDelegate> delegate;
-(void)ArrayGenerator;
@end
```

to

```
@interface ArrayGenerator : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSObject <ArrayGeneratorDelegate> delegate;
-(void)ArrayGenerator;
@end
```

Actually answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8844841/2012219)

Comment: ios 9.1 support arm64 after this error reason [NSTaggedPointerString delegate] unrecognised selector sent.. please help me